# HTML5 New Cache not applying

Tags: html, google-chrome, cache-manifest

I have an HTML5 app that has a large manifest file, containing, among other things, a lot of PDFs. On the first visit, the cache downloads over several minutes and applies properly.

When I make changes and update the manifest accordingly, it reportedly downloads the cache again, however much more quickly, suggesting that it's not actually fetching the files. I'm monitoring the cache events and everything completes without error but none of the changes are made.

If I remove the bulk of the PDFs from the manifest it behaves as it should so I know it's a space issue. Is there a way to programmatically clear the cache before downloading the new files? I'm guessing the fetch isn't happening because it's out of space, but no error event is raised.

Comment: Have you monitored the requests after the manifest update?  The browser might be querying for the new PDFs, but your server may be responding with `304 Not Modified`.

Answer (score 0):

The manifest behavior is vague, if it encounters any problem then the download will interrupt abruptly.

If the content of the manifest file is not changed to the previous version then it will never download any file even if we have modified the listed file. So we use to place a commented line with date time stamp.

If any of the files listed in the manifest is not available in the server, then the download will be stopped, it wont throw any error. Guess in your case, the filename should be wrong or the file doesn't exist.

Hope it helps...